# php while loop - if statement for each row of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a program that queries a mysql db and displays the results in an html table. I want to have conditional formatting based upon one of the field values. If the query returns the word "In", I want the table cell background color to be green; If the word "Out" appears, red. I've gotten to the point where it is coloring the cells, but it appears to be using the color of the first row's word for the first and all subsequent rows. Say, for instance, that the first row's word is "In", then that cell will be green, and all cells below it, even if other cells have the word "Out". Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
...

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Employee'] . "</td>";
            $color_test = $row['Status'];
            if ($color_test = "In") {
                echo "<td bgcolor=#00FF00>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";
                }
            elseif ($color_test = "Out") {
                echo "<td bgcolor=#FF0000>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";
                }
            else {}

            echo "<td>" . $row['Return'] . "</td>";
...
```

The only thing I can think of is that the if statement is not being applied to all rows. I'm not sure how this would be done. I've not programmed much in php.

Comment: Use mysqli_fetch_assoc() instead of mysqli_fetch_array() and you are supposed to use == instead of = in your if statement

Comment: Have you tried an associative array? `$colors = array('In'=>'#00FF00','Out'=>'#FF000')'. Then just use `$colors[$color_test]` on your `bgcolor`.

Comment: `$color_test ==` - times 2.

Answer (score 5):

```
if($color_test = "In")
```

should be

```
if($color_test == "In")
```

Now, you are assigning the "In" string to the variable `$color_test`, but you should check the equality with the `==` operator.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `==` if you are comparing in an if statement

Comment: Duh. That was a gimme. I thought I had tried that already, but apparently not. Thanks for responding, everyone.

Comment: No problem thats what we are here for :D

Answer (score 0):

`while` block should be like this .

```
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Employee'] . "</td>";
        $color_test = $row['Status'];
        if ($color_test == "In") {
            echo "<td bgcolor=#00FF00>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";
            }
        elseif ($color_test == "Out") {
            echo "<td bgcolor=#FF0000>" . $row['Status'] . "</td>";
            }
        else {
              echo "<td>" . $row['Return'] . "</td>";
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

a few corrections :

You're using mysqli_fetch_array() when you're trying to get a row - use mysqli_fetch_assoc() instead.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Inside the if predicates, you are using only one =, which uses for assigning values, use == instead.

```
if( $color_test == "In" )
if( $color_test == "Out" )
```

And just a little comment, you already assigned a variable called $color_test, it would be better if you use this variable at the printing instead using $row[] when printing.

That's all I think

Comment: Makes sense, and I've made the changes. Much appreciated.